# How to echo php errors to main_page from external php file (PHP to HTML echo error)

Tags: php, variables, echo, external

I have a main page called main_page.php with a form and an external form handler called Course.php. The External php files contains variables that should be echoed if user submits empty form. How do I echo these to main_page.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
require_once('/path/to/external.php') // as many of these as you need
```

then you can access the variables from those files. After that just echo the variable(s) needed onto the main file. (For example, if external.php has a variable $var = "test", just echo $var)